# Calculating ratios and put them into a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a table similar to this one, and want to calculate the ratio between column A and B. For example:

```
             A    B     C     D    E     F
     [1,]  187  174   183   115  101   104
     [2,]  451  166   177   842  101   133
     [3,]  727  171   187 12803   98   134
     [4,] 1532  181   196   730   98   108
     [5,] 4139  188   214 20358  105   159
     [6,]  689  185   211  1633  110   162
     [7,] 1625  184   195  2283  109   114
     [8,]  771  181   190   904  105   110
     [9,]  950  177   190  1033  106   112
    [10,]  703  180   191   463  106   110
    [11,] 2052  178   188  2585  100   105
    [12,] 1161  178   187  2874   99   110
    [13,]  214  175   184   173   98   110
    [14,]  473  184   191   971  104   111
    [15,]  756  185   193 14743  107   114
```

I want to create a new matrix that has all of those previous rows as new rows and columns (15 rows and 15 columns) like so (values in parentheses are placeholders for the calculated ratios):

```
          [,1]    [,2]     [,3]    [,4]    
 [1,]  (A1:B1) (A1:B2)  (A1:B3) (A1:B4) ...   
 [2,]  
 [3,]  
 [4,] 
 ...
```

That is maybe not the best example, but I hope it is not too confusing.
To calculate the ratios A1:B1, A2:B2, A3:B3 I could do something like:

```
data.matrix(data["A"]/data["B"])
```

And to do it for all, I would do something like:

```
data.matrix(data[1,]/data[1,1])
data.matrix(data[1,]/data[1,2])
...
```

and so on.
This seems to be a lot of work and maybe someone knows a quicker and more efficient method.

## EDIT

I thought the `combn` function would work, but then I figured out it doesn't. When I have a 2 column matrix, such as:

```
       A       B
 [1,]  187   115
 [2,]  451   842
 [3,]  727 12803
 [4,] 1532   730
 [5,] 4139 20358
 [6,]  689  1633
 [7,] 1625  2283
 [8,]  771   904
 [9,]  950  1033
[10,]  703   463
[11,] 2052  2585
[12,] 1161  2874
[13,]  214   173
[14,]  473   971
[15,]  756 14743
```

And I use the `combn` function to calculate all possible ratios (A1:B1, A1:B2, ... A2:B1, A2:B2...) I get just the result for A1 vs all values of B.

```
> combn(ncol(data), 2, function(x) data[,x[1]]/data[,x[2]])
 [,1]
 [1,] 1.62608696
 [2,] 0.53562945
 [3,] 0.05678357
 [4,] 2.09863014
 [5,] 0.20331074
 [6,] 0.42192284
 [7,] 0.71178274
 [8,] 0.85287611
 [9,] 0.91965150
[10,] 1.51835853
[11,] 0.79381044
[12,] 0.40396660
[13,] 1.23699422
[14,] 0.48712667
[15,] 0.05127857
```

Or maybe I just don't understand the `combn` function and I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: What do expect the result of this two columns to be? the ratios are `A1:B1`, `A2:B2` in a single column is result at the moment.

Comment: Do you want A1:B1 , A1:B2... as first row, then A2:B1, A2:B2, .. as second row and so on?

Comment: yes, exactly like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I seem to have misunderstood the question. The answer is even more simpler using `outer`:

```
# gives the same 15*15 matrix as geektrader's
outer(mm[,1], mm[,2], '/')
```

---

*Old answer (not correct):*

You should use `combn`:

```
# combn(ncol(mm), 2) gives you all possible combinations
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    2     3     3     3     4     4     5
# [2,]    2    3    4    5    6    3    4    5    6     4     5     6     5     6     6

# it also accepts a function argument. we can use it to divide 
# respective columns
mm.div <- combn(ncol(mm), 2, function(x) mm[,x[1]]/mm[,x[2]])

# set column names the matrix
colnames(mm.div) <- combn(colnames(mm), 2, paste, collapse="")
```

Comment: I thought it'd work, but then I figured out it didn't quite do what I wanted. I added my problem to my first post after "EDIT", I would appreciate it if you could help me out here

Comment: @bluewoodtree --- try transposing the results?

Comment: hm, this results in a matrix with 2 rows and 105 columns, which I find very confusing... I don't know which ratio is which. My goal was to get a readable 15x15 matrix with all individual ratios

Comment: @Arun - I think OP hasn't clearly stated what he wants. I have answered using my interpretation of the question

Comment: Basically, my goal was to get it into a format as shown in the second gray code box from the top in my question post.

Comment: @bluewoodtree, sorry, I just corrected. The answer is even simpler with `outer`. Your require a matrix division, basically.

Comment: @Arun, that looks even more elegant and is exactly doing what I wanted now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want by using `expand.grid`, `apply` and `matrix` functions as below

I am assuming what you want is matrix like

```
A1/B1  A1/B2  A1/B3  ...
A2/B1  A2/B2  A2/B3  ...
...    ...    ...    ...
...    ...    ...    ...
```

Here is the code to do that. Explanation in comments

```
txt <- "A    B     C     D    E     F\n187  174   183   115  101   104\n451  166   177   842  101   133\n727  171   187 12803   98   134\n1532  181   196   730   98   108\n4139  188   214 20358  105   159\n689  185   211  1633  110   162\n1625  184   195  2283  109   114\n771  181   190   904  105   110\n950  177   190  1033  106   112\n703  180   191   463  106   110\n2052  178   188  2585  100   105\n1161  178   187  2874   99   110\n214  175   184   173   98   110\n473  184   191   971  104   111\n756  185   193 14743  107   114"

data <- as.matrix(read.table(textConnection(txt), header = TRUE))

# expand.grid : creates every combination of one element each from column A and
# B with elements of B repeated first 

# apply : calls function(x) { x[1]/x[2]) } for every combination outputted by 
# expand.grid 

# matrix : converts the result of apply into matrix. dimnames arguments sets 
# rownames and colnames for easy  verification for us

result <- matrix(apply(expand.grid(data[, "A"], data[, "B"]), 1, function(x) x[1]/x[2]), 
    nrow = nrow(data), dimnames = list(data[, "A"], data[, "B"]))

# note that we have set rownames for result to be values of A and colnames for
# result to be value of B
result
##            174       166       171       181        188       185       184
## 187   1.074713  1.126506  1.093567  1.033149  0.9946809  1.010811  1.016304
## 451   2.591954  2.716867  2.637427  2.491713  2.3989362  2.437838  2.451087
## 727   4.178161  4.379518  4.251462  4.016575  3.8670213  3.929730  3.951087
## 1532  8.804598  9.228916  8.959064  8.464088  8.1489362  8.281081  8.326087
## 4139 23.787356 24.933735 24.204678 22.867403 22.0159574 22.372973 22.494565
## 689   3.959770  4.150602  4.029240  3.806630  3.6648936  3.724324  3.744565
## 1625  9.339080  9.789157  9.502924  8.977901  8.6436170  8.783784  8.831522
## 771   4.431034  4.644578  4.508772  4.259669  4.1010638  4.167568  4.190217
## 950   5.459770  5.722892  5.555556  5.248619  5.0531915  5.135135  5.163043
## 703   4.040230  4.234940  4.111111  3.883978  3.7393617  3.800000  3.820652
## 2052 11.793103 12.361446 12.000000 11.337017 10.9148936 11.091892 11.152174
## 1161  6.672414  6.993976  6.789474  6.414365  6.1755319  6.275676  6.309783
## 214   1.229885  1.289157  1.251462  1.182320  1.1382979  1.156757  1.163043
## 473   2.718391  2.849398  2.766082  2.613260  2.5159574  2.556757  2.570652
## 756   4.344828  4.554217  4.421053  4.176796  4.0212766  4.086486  4.108696
##            181       177       180       178       178       175       184
## 187   1.033149  1.056497  1.038889  1.050562  1.050562  1.068571  1.016304
## 451   2.491713  2.548023  2.505556  2.533708  2.533708  2.577143  2.451087
## 727   4.016575  4.107345  4.038889  4.084270  4.084270  4.154286  3.951087
## 1532  8.464088  8.655367  8.511111  8.606742  8.606742  8.754286  8.326087
## 4139 22.867403 23.384181 22.994444 23.252809 23.252809 23.651429 22.494565
## 689   3.806630  3.892655  3.827778  3.870787  3.870787  3.937143  3.744565
## 1625  8.977901  9.180791  9.027778  9.129213  9.129213  9.285714  8.831522
## 771   4.259669  4.355932  4.283333  4.331461  4.331461  4.405714  4.190217
## 950   5.248619  5.367232  5.277778  5.337079  5.337079  5.428571  5.163043
## 703   3.883978  3.971751  3.905556  3.949438  3.949438  4.017143  3.820652
## 2052 11.337017 11.593220 11.400000 11.528090 11.528090 11.725714 11.152174
## 1161  6.414365  6.559322  6.450000  6.522472  6.522472  6.634286  6.309783
## 214   1.182320  1.209040  1.188889  1.202247  1.202247  1.222857  1.163043
## 473   2.613260  2.672316  2.627778  2.657303  2.657303  2.702857  2.570652
## 756   4.176796  4.271186  4.200000  4.247191  4.247191  4.320000  4.108696
##            185
## 187   1.010811
## 451   2.437838
## 727   3.929730
## 1532  8.281081
## 4139 22.372973
## 689   3.724324
## 1625  8.783784
## 771   4.167568
## 950   5.135135
## 703   3.800000
## 2052 11.091892
## 1161  6.275676
## 214   1.156757
## 473   2.556757
## 756   4.086486
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. This is really a great post, and I really appreciate the explanations! If have just one more question: I am still not sure when to use `as.matrix()` and `data.matrix`, for example I can substitute `data <- as.matrix(...` by `data <- data.matrix(...` and the result will be the same

Comment: @bluewoodtree see `?data.matrix` in R. The value section of that help pages states that it returns `If frame inherits from class "data.frame", an integer or numeric matrix of the same dimensions as frame, with dimnames taken from the row.names (or NULL, depending on rownames.force) and names.

Otherwise, the result of as.matrix.`

Comment: @geektrader, whenever you think of `expand.grid`, think about `outer`.

Comment: @Arun yes. `outer` does seem like better function

Answer (score 0):

I might be completely missing the point here, but why not just use a couple for loops?  I wrote a quick function, then you could pass the pairs to.

For example:

```
A <- rnorm(15)
B <- rnorm(15)
data <- data.frame(A,B)

ratio <- function(input1, input2){
    out <- matrix(0, nrow=length(input1), ncol=length(input1))
    k <- 1
    for (i in 1:length(input1)){
        for (j in 1:length(input1)){
            out[k, j] <- input1[k] / input2[j]
        }
        k <- k + 1
    }
    return(out)
}

ratio(data$A, data$B)
```

**EDIT**

Another thought.  To then use the function to do all possible pairs of ratios, you could simply add another for loop, like this:

```
combs <- combn(1:4, 2)
out <- list()
for (i in 1:(length(combs)/2)){
    out[[i]] <- ratio(data[,combs[1,i]], data[,combs[2,i]])
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: loops as such are frowned upon in R.

Comment: Because this will be inefficient as `R` is vectorized.

Comment: That makes sense, sorry!  geektrader, your solution is definitely more elegant, thanks for posting it.